What does this formula of Electric potential generated by spherical symmetric charge density mean?
I found this formula (14.5) in the book Classical Electromagnetism in a Nutshell by Anupam Garg,
$$\phi(r) = \frac{1}{r} \int_0^r 4\pi r^2\rho(r)\;dr+\int_r^{\infty}4 \pi r\rho(r)\;dr.$$

I know it's done this way using the charge integral like $\phi = \int \frac{\rho}{r} dv$, but I didn't understand the part where the first term is inside the sphere and the second is outside. And I don't know how to use it to get the potential of a solid charged spherelike
$$\phi(r)=\frac{Q}{r},\; \;r>R \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \phi(r)=\frac{Q}{2R^3}(3R^2-r^2),\;\;r<R.$$
Please if you can give me the calculation process about it.

The notation in (14.5) is a little bad. The $r$ inside the integral should be $r'$ so that the integration variable and the variable in the limits are not the same.  That causes some confusion. Otherwise, all you have to do to use this expression is to insert the charge density $\rho(r)$, which will be a function of the radius $R$ of the charge distribution. For a uniform charge, this is $\rho(r') = Q/(\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3)$ for $r'<R$ and 0 for $r'>R$. Then, do the integral for $r<R$ and $r>R$.

First off, write the potential as @march suggested to differentiate between the limit and variable of integration:
$\phi(r)=\frac{1}{r} \int_{0}^{r}4\pi r'^2 \rho(r') \,dr'+ \int_{r}^{\infty} 4\pi r'\rho(r') \,dr'$.
For a uniformly charged sphere,
$\rho=Q/(\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3)$.
When $r>R$,
$\frac{1}{r} \int_{0}^{R}4\pi r'^2 \rho \,dr'$
$=\frac{1}{r}\frac{4\pi}{3}R^3\rho$
$=\frac{Q}{r}$. (Keep in mind that $\rho=0$ for $r'>R$)
For $r<R$, take the limit from $0$ to $r$ in the first integral and $r$ to $R$ in the second integral as shown,
$\frac{1}{r} \int_{0}^{r}4\pi r'^2 \rho \,dr'+\frac{1}{r} \int_{r}^{R}4\pi r' \rho \,dr'$
Note that here $\rho\neq 0$ for $r'>r$ as $r$ is inside the sphere.Now see if you can arrive at the final expression.

Thank you very much for your answer! There is just one mistake in second term of the last equation, do not have factor $\frac{1}{r}$ in front of the $\int^R_r$. Other than that I really appreciate your help in understanding the problem.

Yeah that was a typo. If you remove $\frac{1}{r}$ and proceed with the calculation you will arrive at the final result.
